# JPA 2.1 call stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, entity, jpa-2.1

new to JPA programming here.
trying to figure out the best way to call a stored procedure in sql server  from JPA.

I saw a lot of example of using createSQLQuery. but I am thinking to use createStoredProcedureQuery provided from JPA 2.1

the stored procedure simply took one input parameter and returns back with a select statement (no output declared)

```
PROCEDURE X
@parametername varchar
as
select
a.name
from a where a. id=parametername
```

how to do this with createStoredProcedureQuery ? the example I found needs to have an output parameter but there is no output parameter here? I am guessing I miss something.  is there some example?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute yours stored procedure something like this:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("procedure_name");
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("param1", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.setParameter("param1", 123);
query.execute();
List result = query.getResultList();
```